# Why this numerical integration takes so long?

Tags: numerical-integration

Let me explain the problem. I am trying to integrate a one dimensional integral:
$$\int {g\left( {{k_x}},parameter1,parameter2,...\right)d{\mkern 1mu} {k_x}} $$

for the sake of clarity, I will give function `g` in the last.

I choose a specific set of parameter, and do the following integration:

```
In:=NIntegrate[g[kx, 9, -2, 7, 1, 1, 0.05], {kx, -\[Pi]/3,\[Pi]/3}]//AbsoluteTiming

Out:={422.396160, 0.163126 + 0.103155 I}
```

This takes me 422s on my computer!!!

I use the following code to show the sampling points used during the integration.

```
sampp = Reap[
 NIntegrate[#, {kx, -\[Pi]/(3), \[Pi]/(3)}, 
  EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{kx, #}]]] &[
g[kx, 9, -2, 7, 1, 1, 0.05]] ;
{Length[#], ListPlot[#, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Filling -> Axis]} &[
 relist@sampp[[2, 2, 1]]]
```

[image: sampling points]

it shows that it used 733 sample points. But should that take 400 seconds?

Actually, **the evaluation of the integrand at each sample point is acually fast.** I use the most simple interpolation method to do the same integration as below, I use 1000 sample points that is evenly distributed and it only takes 1.3 second. Besides the integration result is quite accurate.

```
In:=(sampp = Table[{kx, 
 g[kx, 9, -2, 7, 1, 1, 0.05]}, {kx, -\[Pi]/3, \[Pi]/3, 
 2 \[Pi]/3/1000}];
Integrate[
Interpolation[sampp, InterpolationOrder -> 2][
x], {x, -\[Pi]/3, \[Pi]/3}]) // AbsoluteTiming
Out:={1.308075, 0.163126 + 0.103155 I}
```

So what did *Mathematica* do in the extremely long 400 second? Of course, it needs to do many error estimation, but that should not take too much time.

I scan the documents and related questions in stackexchange. Somebody suggest to set "SymbolicProcessing"->0. OK, I tried

```
In:=NIntegrate[g[kx, 9, -2, 7, 1, 1, 0.05], {kx, -\[Pi]/3,     \[Pi]/3}, 
Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", Method -> "GaussKronrodRule", 
"SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]//AbsoluteTiming
Out:={401.791981, 0.163126 + 0.103155 I}
```

unfortunately, the result is the same.

Even more peculiar, when I use "Trapezoidal" strategy and limit the MaxRecursion

```
 In:=NIntegrate[g[kx, 9, -2, 7, 1, 1, 0.05], {kx, -\[Pi]/3, \[Pi]/3}, 
 Method -> "Trapezoidal", MinRecursion -> 1, MaxRecursion -> 4]
Out:={413.894674, 0.163126 + 0.103155 I}
```

the sample points shows as follows
[image: sample points2]
it only used 257 sample point, but the time cost is the same??!!It is unbelievable! Anyway, I think the "Trapezoidal" should be the same as evenly sample interpolation method.

**I really can't understand what did *Mathematica* do in the `NIntegrate` of function g. Can somebody explain it?**

**Of course, it seems that I can use the simple interpolation integration method manually, because it is fast, and the result seems good in this case. But it is not robust, I insisted using the built in "Adaptive" strategy, because I have to Integrate some other functions which are sharp at specific points.**

---

In the last
the form of function `g`

```
g[kx_, xx_, e_, width_, ii_, label_, \[Eta]_] := 
Inverse[(e - I \[Eta]) IdentityMatrix[2*width] - 
 armchairibbonmat[kx, width]][[2*(ii - 1) + label, 
2*(ii - 1) + label]] E^(I kx xx)

(*armchairibbonmat is a function used in function g*)

armchairibbonmat[kx_, n_] :=
(
h = Table[0, {i, 1, 2 (n + 2)}, {j, 1, 2 (n + 2)}];
a[m_] := 2 m - 1;
b[m_] := 2 m;
t1 = 1;
aa = 1;
Do[
h[[b[i], a[i]]] = t1 E^(I kx aa);
h[[a[i], b[i]]] = t1 E^(-I kx aa);
h[[b[i + 1], a[i]]] = t1 E^(-I kx aa/2);
h[[b[i - 1], a[i]]] = t1 E^(-I kx aa/2);
h[[a[i - 1], b[i]]] = t1 E^(I kx aa/2);
h[[a[i + 1], b[i]]] = t1 E^(I kx aa/2);
, {i, 2, n + 1}];
h = ArrayPad[h, -2]
)
```

Comment: Sorry, everyone, I made a few typoerrors in the definition of function g at first, but now it is fixed. thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you replace

```
g[kx_,
```

with

```
g[kx_?NumericQ
```

Things will work as you expect.

Update: Evaluation of

```
g[kx, 9, -2, 7, 1, 1, 0.05]
```

takes a long time and the `_?NumericQ` absolutely prevents the symbolic evaluation.

Comment: I *like* short answers that get to the point!

Comment: @ruebenko it works!! Thank you!! If I would know the answer is so simple, I would not have written such a long detailed question, HaHa

Comment: @ruebenko  But why this fixed the problem? Can you explain a little?

Comment: See update, there many similar examples in this forum, have a look.

Comment: @ruebenko but why "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0 didn't work?

Comment: @matheorem, that does not totally prevent symbolic evaluation it just switches off some processing.